# App does not load in emulator

Tags: java, android

I am facing this issue for quite long time.

Creating a small android app 
Whenever I try to run my Activity.java file in Android,emulator opens. After that I keep seeing this message as "Waiting for the target device to come online" for around 10 minutes. After that,when the gradle build gets finished, emulator stays as it is and app is not loaded or visible in the emulator.

This has happened to me many times and I failed to resolve this as I don't see any error message when gradle build is finished.

Any help is much appreciated. I have an assignment lined up to be completed in 2 days. Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Have you ever had an emulator run? Not all computers support the virtualization needed to run an emulator.

Comment: Emulator runs but app does not  get loaded.Thats the problem. FYI, my System is 64-bit ,Windows 10. If  Not all computers support the virtualization, then can I run my app on Android device to check in real time if it works?

Comment: you need about 8 GB ram and update to newest android studio. Old android studio was very slow with the AVD. You can also create additional AVD's https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html you may also not have resources https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html see the section providing additional resources so you can provide resources to fit the device

Comment: @user3624146 You can always use your phone to run your app directly. In that case you have to turn on `USB Debugging Mode` in your phone. Else check my answer below if it is helpful.

Comment: Hi, I ran this app on my  android device.Now , I am able to see the app in my app list but when click on the app , I am getting this error message as  "App stopped working Close app".  Any reason behind this?  Need to know one more thing, when I ran the app on real device it said, "Android Studio 2.3.2 Launching the app under a work profile or another user account on the target device will result in a crash"  What does it mean? I am new to this Android programming so do not know what it means.